# Access-Control-Allow-Method being mysteriously re-written

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway

Ok, so I have a very simple API gateway with a lambda function provisioned through it. The following OPTIONS method has been defined on it for CORS:

```
"ServerStatusOptions": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
  "Properties": {
    "ResourceId": {"Ref": "ServerStatusApiResource"},
    "RestApiId": {"Ref": "ServerStatusApi"},
    "AuthorizationType": "NONE",
    "HttpMethod": "OPTIONS",
    "Integration": {
      "Type": "MOCK",
      "IntegrationResponses": [
        {
          "StatusCode": 200,
          "ResponseParameters": {
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'GET,OPTIONS'",
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
              "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "'" , { "Fn::Join" : [ ".", [ "xonotic", { "Ref" : "ZoneName" } ] ] }, "'" ]] 
            }
          },
          "ResponseTemplates": { "application/json": "" }
      }],
      "PassthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
      "RequestTemplates": { "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}" }
    },
    "MethodResponses": [ {
      "StatusCode": 200,
      "ResponseModels": { "application/json": "Empty"},
      "ResponseParameters": {
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": false,
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": false,
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": false
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

If I use the TEST function within the API gateway, I see the headers as I've set them up, so thing are at least working that far.

And yet when my javascript attempts to call the API it gets a CORS error and when I manually perform an OPTIONS query using curl I see Access-Control-Allow-Methods returning POST,OPTIONS as the allowed methods.

The expected methods are OPTIONS (for CORS) and GET (To fetch a current status). Here's the results of invoking CURL.

```
...
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 0
< date: Sun, 01 Dec 2019 00:47:25 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: 13e78191-cc4a-45ba-87ba-fa954fde6936
< access-control-allow-origin: xonotic.deimos-legion.net
< access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
< x-amz-apigw-id: D_8QoFuuSwMFm5Q=
< access-control-allow-methods: POST,OPTIONS
< x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 b53881e988d60469224197aff16f631a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: SYD1-C2
< x-amz-cf-id: J7IZbKmuopZswwgVZI6XSuYxPfWxP8o1vm-g_FfENpvWYCbwzCEpqg==
<
```

Comment: Please share your `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` GET resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the culprit here turns out to be that when you update the method ResponseParameters attribute via CloudFormation, CloudFormation doesn't perform a re-deploy of the stage you've changed (it's not clear precisely what changes will or won't trigger a deployment of the change).

Going in and manually deploying the stage causes the change to take effect.

Looks like I have to ensure the GET method is correctly returning the same information, but that's a separate issue I'll have to look into.